# ORACLE SQL : How to display the occurence number of a column content in a sorted table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to display the occurence number of a column content in a sorted table

Here is my table REF content with two columns :

```
POSITION| MYVAL
---------------
   1    | U
   2    | U
   3    | B
   4    | R
   5    | R
   6    | R
   7    | C
```

I would like to have such result table (introducing a NO_OCCURENCE column which display the occurence number of MYVAL content):

```
  POSITION | NO_OCCURENCE| MYVAL
  --------------------------------
     1     |     1       |   U
     2     |     2       |   U
     3     |     1       |   B
     4     |     1       |   R
     5     |     2       |   R
     6     |     3       |   R
     7     |     1       |   C
```

How can I do such in ORACLE SQL?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Ranking functions. Refer [RANK, DENSE_RANK, FIRST and LAST Analytic Functions](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php).

```
SELECT POSITION, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MYVAL ORDER BY POSITION ASC) AS NO_OCCURENCE, 
       MYVAL
FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It matches perfectly with what I expect! 
Note : RANK() fits well my need because POSITION column is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function for this:

```
select position,
       row_number() over (partition by myval order by position) as no_occurence, 
       myval
from the_table
order by position, myval;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It also match! However I also tested Kumar solution below.  I took RANK() analytic function. I really don't know what is the best between RANK() and ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @LaurentTOURREAU They are different. In your posted example and desired output, **row_number** would suffice. See an example here http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0320__Analytical-Functions/UseROWNUMBERRANKandDENSERANKtogether.htm